# Show that every large integer has a large prime-power factor

Tags: analysis, elementary-number-theory

Show that every large integer has a large prime-power factor

That is, if $P(n)$ designates the largest number $p^a$ which divides $n$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}P(n)=\infty.$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT Show that for every $M \in \mathbb N$, there exists $N = N(M) \in \mathbb N$ such that $$ P(n) \leq M \implies n \leq N .$$ 
Why does this statement prove that $P(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: What does your answer mean?

Comment: @Z_Fang It's just a hint. I can elaborate on the hint, but anon's answer already explains the idea nicely.

Comment: Actually it is a problem (Page 11) in Fundamentals of Number Theory, by William J. Leveque

Comment: How about considering the converse-negative proposition for $ P(n) \leq M \implies n \leq N $ ?

Comment: @Z_Fang: If you mean the [contrapositive](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contraposition), then that's also valid because it's logically equivalent.

Comment: @anon But he asked, "Why does this statement prove that $P(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$?" Could the contrapositive reveal that?

Comment: @Z_Fang Well, actually, there's not much to prove there. The first sentence is essentially the definition of "$P(n) \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$".

Answer (score 6):

$\rm\bf Guide$: Let $p^a$ be a prime power. There are only finitely many prime powers less than it, and every natural can be uniquely written as a product of prime powers. Use this to show that the number of naturals $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P(n)=p^a$ is finite, no matter what $p^a$ is. Along these lines, for given $p^a$, what *explicitly* is the largest $n$ such that $P(n)=p^a$? What does this mean for $P(\cdot)$ for all $\cdot>n$? How does this show that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} P(n)=\infty$?